# Protocol between two view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use protocols between two view controllers. I tried like this:

```
protocol ReceivedPhotosDelegate{
    func reloadData()
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var recivedDelegate: ReceivedPhotosDelegate?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.recivedDelegate!.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And second class:

```
class ReceivedPhotosViewController: UIViewController,ReceivedPhotosDelegate {

    func reloadData() {
        print("test ok")
    }
}
```

When I run this code I am getting following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

for this line:

```
self.recivedDelegate!.reloadData()
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show us how you create `SecondViewController`?

Comment: where did you set ReceivedPhotosViewController is delegate of SecondViewController

Comment: **common delegate mistake #1:** forgetting to set the delegate. You also shouldn't be force unwrapping the delegate as there may well be times when you don't want it to be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `ReceivedPhotosViewController` you should be setting recievedDelegate. Add following line to `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of `ReceivedPhotosViewController`

```
secondVC.recivedDelegate = self    //assuming secondVC is instance of SecondViewController
```

All while calling reloadData do nil check

```
if self.recievedDelegate != nil {
    self.recivedDelegate!.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Why not just `receivedDelegate?.reloadData()`?

Comment: Just in case recievedDelegate is not set, your app won't crash. Always safe way to check for nil checks

Comment: But isn't it why you can use `optional chaining` for this? `reloadData()` won't be called unless the delegate has been set.